# want to pass the post value in to controller

Tags: codeigniter, variables

Here am having the code like this

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Start Date</label>
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" required name="attendance_date" id="attendance_date" class="form-control datepicker" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" data-date-format="<?= config_item('date_picker_format'); ?>" required>
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
</div>

<a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button" name="update" href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/attendance_confirmation/reject1/<?php echo $this->input->post('attendance_date');?>" id="update1" value="Reject"  class="btn btn-danger ml" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i> <?= lang('reject') ?></a>
```

and my controller looks like this

```
 public function reject1($date)
{


     $data['date']=$date;
     var_dump($data['date']);

    $data['modal_subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/engineer_attendance_confirmation/attendance_confirmation_modal',$data,FALSE);
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $data);

}
```

but the value in the `attendance_date` is not getting in controller.how can we pass the value in the post to the controller using href tag

Comment: You may use ajax to do that

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, POST data isn't passed through as variables into the controller function.  You'd instead need to use the [input library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html).  You can then use `$this->input->post()` to get POST data:

```
$data['date'] = $this->input->post('attendance_date');
```

Comment: but how the value of the post will be gone to controller i mean `$this->input->post('attendance_date')`

Answer (score 0):

Using href tag you don't get data in the post, but you can get the data using a segment like this:

```
public function reject1()
{
 $data['date']=$this->uri->segment(3);
 var_dump($data['date']);
 $data['modal_subview'] =  $this->load->view('admin/engineer_attendance_confirmation/attendance_confirmation_modal',$data,FALSE);
 $this->load->view('admin/_layout_modal', $data);
}
```